# Installing maven depencies from pom.xml in docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I am trying to run a spring-boot maven project inside a docker environment. So the setup is as follows:

1. Docker is set up and installs Java, etc. (done only once)
2. App is run (can be any number of times)

### What I am experiencing

Every time I run the spring-boot project by `mvn spring-boot:run`, it installs all the required libraries (**every time I run the project**) from the `pom.xml` (Java, Maven, etc. are preinstalled from the docker) and then runs the project.

### What I am trying to do

This process of reinstalling every time is redundant and time-consuming, so I want to *delegate* this installation thing to the docker as well. Ideally, using the `pom.xml` to do the installations, though alternative ways are also welcome.

### What I have tried so far

- Install `npm` [using a good tutorial](https://www.mariokandut.com/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager/), but it fails in Docker as we can't restart the terminal during docker build, while `source ~/.bash_profile` doesn't seem to work either.
- Tried to build that project directly in docker (by `RUN mvn clean install --fail-never`) and copying both `npm` and `node` folders to the directory where I run the app. But it doesn't seem to work either as it's installing them every time without any change.

Can anyone please help me there? This problem has stuck the project. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand why you want to run your spring-boot project via maven. Why are you not packaging a war or an executable jar and running that?

Comment: @tgdavies Well if there's any solution for the given setup (jar/war), I am up to trying that. Please share it.

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging

Comment: I don't understand what your are trying to do. Do you want to build a docker image?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Basically the app is running in a docker setup and want to install the dependencies of the project right in the docker, so they don't have to be installed every time I run the app.

Comment: There's an [official guide about Spring Boot with Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/). Did you try that? Btw, why `node`/`npm`? This has apparently nothing to do with Java / Spring Boot…

Comment: Still don't understand your requirement. What do you mean by "right in the docker"?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I mean all the required libraries should be installed in the docker at the start and not on the compile time.

Comment: That's not how Maven works.

Comment: I would suggest to build your application outside of docker and put only the resulting application (spring-boot app jar) into the docker... this will use your local cache which prevents downloading every time. You could do the same in the docker but you have to build once and save the local cache as a volume or a container. Also you could mount the local cache from outside into. the docker container...

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that, in the Dockerfile you just install java, maven, etc. but does not build your project using `mvn clean package install` before executing `mvn spring-boot:run` (and that is redundant as well because `mvn spring-boot:run` does the build for you before staring the application).

You cannot skip installing maven dependency while running on containers as they are spun as they run. So it will be installed either while you call `mvn clean install` or `mvn spring-boot:run`.

What the max you can do is, using your devops pipeline, build the jar previously and in the Dockerfile just copy the build jar and execute.

Example Dockerfile in this case:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Here the previously build artifact is already available at `target/`

Comment: This `mvn clean package install` will repeat several steps which is not a good idea... you need only `mvn clean install` and for putting the resulting file (app.jar) into docker container you don't need to do `install` only `mvn clean package` is sufficient...

Comment: That's right.. `mvn package` is sufficient if done on the container, but if done on the pipeline on some other vm `mvn install` will do.

Comment: `install` is usually never needed neither in a pipeline. A package will create the needed jar file in target directory which can be picked up for copying into docker image...... within a pipeline like on a CI you should use `mvn deploy` and deploy artifacts into a repository manager...